# Record Google Analytics with PHP? Possible?

Tags: php

I use Google Analytics and love it, I have all the goals and conversions setup etc. It works great.

My current task is recording mobile apps. I do not want to hard code it into the App due to ease of changing methods, so I plan on planting the analytics in the mobile API (which is in PHP). I would like to record google analytics events using PHP instead of Javascript.

I know there is a PHP API for Google analytics, but I think this is for reporting only. What would you suggest doing? Maybe a CURL or something? Im lost!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work: http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/

Comment: You should also take a look at this: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingTroubleshooting.html#gifParameters

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/